# Has there ever been a movie that was cancelled after the trailer was released?

Tags: production, trailers, cancellation

Productions usually get cancelled before or during preproduction, but I'm wondering whether there has ever been a film which had a cancelled release, after the trailer debuted.

**Criteria:**

- Movie has to be a feature-length, Hollywood studio production
- Trailer has to contain actual scene footage (a teaser like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T--w5DGclsM) which only serves to pitch the idea and some of the actors involved and the title of the movie without showing actual footage doesn't count)
- Cancellation means the production was halted and the movie did not make a release (wide release, domestic, select or even home-video release)

Comment: 10 Things I Hate About Life

Comment: May want to clarify the criteria you are looking for, such as from a Hollywood Studio or Worldwide, or if you're considering a teaser trailer (usually very short) or the actual full length trailer (about two minutes).  I'd be willing to guess that more movies that are "teased" have never made it to release.

Comment: By cancelled release, do you mean the movie never made it to home video, either?

Comment: @aryxus and sonnik good points. Editing now.

Comment: Not too long ago I watched __[Doomed: The Untold Story of Roger Corman's the Fantastic Four](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3113456/)__, which is a documentary about the 1994 version of __[The Fantastic Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fantastic_Four_(unreleased_film))__. Trailers were shown, the cast did promotion at comic conventions, the world premiere was supposed to take place at the Mall of America ... but as it turned out, the film was never intended to actually be released (unbeknownst to the cast and crew).

Comment: Yeah, there's confusion about whether or not Corman made that movie solely to retain the rights until technology improved, or if he really made an attempt at a legit movie.  That question has never really been answered 100%.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - It was __[Bernd Eichinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernd_Eichinger)__ who had the rights. He asked Roger Corman if he could produce a movie for very little money. I think it's possible that even Corman didn't know the real reason until close to the end of production.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be an evolving list, so it might get closed, but [Empires Of The Deep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empires_of_the_Deep) never saw a release, despite having a [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3dnwxUSK9k) made.

Also, [All American Massacre](http://horror.wikia.com/wiki/All_American_Massacre), a short film by Tobe Hooper's son, never ended up getting released despite having a [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWY6nj4roBM) made.

And, of course, Roger Corman's disaster of a movie [The Fantastic Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fantastic_Four_(unreleased_film)) had a [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_X5C6e3ZeY) released.

Comment: Woah, that's insane! Empires of the Deep went well over 100 million - it's *complete* though, I don't understand why they wouldn't release it in order to get at least *some* money back. The other two movies didn't look so big budget, with Fantastic 4 being a million dollars and I didn't see how much All American Massacre cost, but it couldn't have been more than a million I'd assume.

Comment: If the answer meets the criteria proposed in the question, the question becomes a "Yes" or "No" question, in which answers can say "Yes, there have, here is an/some example(s)", but it's true that it verges on list-making, which I'm aware isn't allowed, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: With the new criteria posted, The Fantastic Four movie would fit that bill.  Empires Of The Deep was/is a US/China co-production so it may not be considered completely "Hollywood".